# ARKit crashing on iPad Air 1

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

So I wanted to try ARKit. I installed iOS 11 on my iPad air but it keeps crashing.
Here's the code in my view controller

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
   @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let scene = SCNScene()
       sceneView.scene = scene
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        let configuration = ARSessionConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
}
```

So I searched up a bit and I came into this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/building_a_basic_ar_experience
which basically says that for devices that has an older chip than the A9, should use ARSessionConfiguration instead of ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration however I still keep getting crashes.
I tried the ARKit Demp provided by Apple, same thing.
I also tried `sceneView.antialiasingMode = .none` but it didn't help either.

Here's the console log I get when it crashes

> 2017-06-26 21:44:16.539469+0200 ARKitGame[562:56168] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
>   2017-06-26 21:44:18.630888+0200 ARKitGame[562:55915] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
>   2017-06-26 21:44:18.633276+0200 ARKitGame[562:55915] Metal API Validation Enabled
>   2017-06-26 21:44:19.625366+0200 ARKitGame[562:56176] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-06-26 21:44:19.628963+0200 ARKitGame[562:56176] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>   2017-06-26 21:44:22.706910+0200 ARKitGame[562:56176] -[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:], line 778: error 'MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (520).'
>   -[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:]:778: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (520).'
>   (lldb)

Comment: It's a beta OS. Are you sure that iPad revision is fully supported?

Comment: Yup I just downloaded it today. It's the latest iOS 11 beta.

Comment: It's probably going to crash now and then, that's the nature of beta soft
ware.

Comment: probably should file a radar, if you think it should work...

Comment: Well apparently Apple released a 24 mb update today. I'm currently downloading it and testing. But according to the change logs, this should have been fixed with iOS 11 Beta 2 which is what I already have.

Comment: Nope didn't work :S

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed the [ARKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) with beta 2: it now unequivocally says that ARKit as a whole -- not just world tracking -- requires A9.

Perhaps that explains why even the basic session configuration seemed to never actually work on devices below A9...

Comment: That's interesting.
`print(ARSessionConfiguration.isSupported)`
`print(ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration.isSupported)`
Both return true when run on my iPad Air. I thought `ARSessionConfiguration` would be the only one that returns true.
I really wonder if they will bring it back to devices lower than A9.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the latest beta and run it on iPad Air 1 and still crashes and as Apple mentioned here : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit

> Important ARKit requires an iOS device with an **A9** or later processor.
>   To make your app available only on devices supporting ARKit, use the
>   arkit key in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section of your app's
>   Info.plist. If augmented reality is a secondary feature of your app,
>   use the  isSupported  property to determine whether the current device
>   supports the session configuration you want to use.

So it seems it only works on A9 processors.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit only works on A9 chips onward: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/06/list-iphone-ipad-compatible-arkit-ios-11.html

iPad Air 1 has an A7 chip, so i would think maybe that's the crash you are seeing.

**Updated:** Didnt notice your comment about older chips using ARSessionConfiguration instead of ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration. Maybe you could try changing this settings on the ARKit demo app.

Comment: Yea, this is what I did. Didn't work. It's driving me crazy. I also read something about ARSessionConfiguration being disabled for devices that have earlier chips but it will be enabled in a later beta version. So far we're at Beta 2 and it doesn't seem to work.